# RESTful API design: should unchangable data in an update (PUT) be optional?

Tags: rest, put

I'm in the middle of implementing a RESTful API, and I am unsure about the 'community accepted' behavior for the presence of data that can not change. For example, in my API there is a 'file' resource that when created contains a number of fields that can not be modified after creation, such as the file's binary data, and some metadata associated with it. Additionally, the 'file' can have a written description, and tags associated.

My question concerns doing an update to one of these 'file' resources. A GET of a specific 'file' will return all the metadata, description & tags associated with the file, plus the file's binary data. Should a PUT of a specific 'file' resource include the 'read only' fields? I realize that it can be coded either way: a) include the read only fields in the PUT data and then verify they match the original (or issue an error), or b) ignore the presence of the read only fields in the PUT data because they can't change, never issuing an error if they don't match or are missing because the logic ignores them.

Seems like it could go either way and be acceptable. The second method of ignoring the read only fields can be more compact, because the API client can skip sending that read only data if they want; which seems good for people who know what they are doing...

Comment: Just a note:  Roy Fielding says that PUT is not to be used for partial updates.  http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rest-discuss/message/17421  For partial updates use POST.  PUT is used to *replace* the resource at the given URL. See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2443344/48082  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2391954/48082

Answer (score 17):

Personally, both ways are acceptable.... however, if I were you, I'll opt for option A (check read-only fields to ensure they are not changed, else throw an error). Depending on the scope of your project, you cannot assume what the consumers know about your Restful WS in depth because most of them don't read documentations or WADL, even if they are the experienced ones. :)

If you don't provide immediate feedback to the consumers that certain fields are read-only, they will have a false assumption that your web service will take care all the changes they have made without double checking, **OR** once they find out the "inconsistent" updates, they complain to others that your web service is buggy.

You can approach this in two different ways if the read-only field doesn't match the original values...

1. Don't process the request. Send a 409 Conflict code and specific error message.
2. Process the request, send a 200 OK and a message stating that changes made the read-only fields are ignored.

Answer (score 17):

Unless the read-only data makes up a significant portion of the data (to the extreme that transmitting the read-only data has a noticeable impact on network traffic and response times), you should write the service to accept the read only fields in the PUT and check them for changes.  It's just simpler to have the same data going in and out.

Look at it this way:  You could make inclusion of the read only fields optional in the PUT, but you will still have to / should write the code in the service to check that any read only fields that were received contain the expected values.  You have to write the read only checking either way.

Prohibiting the read-only fields in the PUT is a bad idea because it will require the clients to strip away fields they received from you in the GET.  This requires that the client get more intimately involved with your data and semantics than they really need to be.  The clients will consider this a headache, an unnecessary complication, and downright mean of you to add to their burden.  Taking data received from your GET, modifying one field of interest, and sending it back to you with a PUT should be a brain-dead simple  round-trip for the client.  Don't complicate things when you don't have to.